# How can I prevent the odor in my dishwasher?

Tags: equipment

My dishwasher is emitting a strong bad odor when its door is open. It's a settled odor resulting from a mix of the accumulated dishes together with the plastic material inside. Even if the machine stays empty, the odor is always there.

What can I do to destroy this odor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try throwing some baking soda and lemon juice in it and run an empty load without soap. Repeat as needed.

I'd try about half a normal sized box of baking soda and half to a whole cup of lemon juice.

Comment: Baking soda is the cleaning solution that powers so much else.

Answer (score 1):

[Hobodave](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/how-can-i-prevent-the-odor-in-my-dishwasher/5092#5092) has the right solution, in addition i would suggest you a product like [this](http://www.partmaster.co.uk/cgi-bin/product.pl?PID=1506532&query=%20finish%20tablet) to keep the dishwater's odor fresh.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, I've had very good luck with [Dishwasher Magic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HE9YVU).